# Background image gets cut off at bottom

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a bg image for a div which itself is height and width 100% (i.e. it covers the entire browser window).

This image gets cut off the bottom though. I have already tried things like background-size: cover; and height: 100%; width: 100%. Nothing seems to stop the bottom being cut off. I tried resizing the src image itself making it tiny and the bottom is still cut off?

HTML:

```
<div id="des" class="full-window">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#des {
    background: url("bg.png");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.full-window {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I do not mind stretch at this stage.

Comment: What's the size of `bg.png`? Could you post the picture? And maybe make a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) which demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 1):

you are missing background properties to fit image without cutting.
try this

```css
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: From my understanding `cover` will clip the background image.

Comment: I do not want it fixed though. The whole site is 1 webpage with full window sections that you scroll down through, from beginning to end. This is the bg img for 1 section.